# how to do automation on the opened IE webpage using VBScript

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, automation, html

I want to do some clicks on buttons and select drop downs on opened webpage(IE) using vb script.

I tried with some but it not working some times.

#### Code snippet

```
Option Explicit
Dim IE,WshShell,surl,shapp
surl="https://oss.corp.hp.com/os/os.tcl?modifyrep=AA+OF+Express+shipment"
set shapp=createobject("shell.application")
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
While IE.Busy
  WScript.Sleep 1000
Wend
For Each IE In shapp.Windows
    For Each a In ie.document.getElementsByTagname("a")
        If a.href = "javascript:DelFilters()" Then
            a.Click
        End If  
    Next
    Wscript.Sleep 10000
    IE.Document.All.Item("filterfields").SelectedIndex = 219
    IE.Document.All.Item("filterfields").FireEvent ("onchange")
    'Wscript.Sleep 10000
    Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("filterval")
    Helem.Value = "82P980080009"
 
    
Next
    set shapp=Nothing
```

Comment: Describe hat happens when it's "not working".

Comment: i need to click button or select drop down on opened webpage (IE) only , but code not performing action. Please give one example for simple click on opened webpage(IE) using vbscript

Comment: Your code does not look too bad on first glace. But without an error description that's more detailed than "sometimes it does not work" it's nearly impossible to help you. You can try to debug your code with the interactive debugger in the VBA editor of Microsoft Office (set breakpoints, step through the code, inspect variables). That's a lot more convenient than debugging inside VBScript with `MsgBox`. But until you have a proper error description it would be pure luck if anyone could tell you what's wrong.

Comment: tell me small example for this. i need some action (automation) on already opened webpage. please help using Vbscript

Answer (score 0):

No need for **WScript.Shell**. Use **InternetExplorer.Application**. It will open IE for you:

```
Option Explicit
Dim IE,surl
surl="https://oss.corp.hp.com/os/os.tcl?modifyrep=AA+OF+Express+shipment"

'IE init:
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate surl

While IE.Busy
  WScript.Sleep 1000
Wend

'from now on, it depends on the page contents:
For Each a In IE.document.getElementsByTagname("a")
    If a.href = "javascript:DelFilters()" Then
        a.Click
    End If  
Next
Wscript.Sleep 10000
IE.Document.All.Item("filterfields").SelectedIndex = 219
IE.Document.All.Item("filterfields").FireEvent ("onchange")
'Wscript.Sleep 10000
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("filterval")
Helem.Value = "82P980080009"
```

I could not access your example page, so I tried on others. Not sure if errors won't raise after IE is open and IE.document's methods are called, but I think your problem was to open IE to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, I think we have a misunderstood. You **don't** need to create a web page with a vbscript code. Just save this code to a file with extension **.vbs** and double click it. Then, Internet Explorer will open and the document will be modified according to what follows the **for now on** comment.

Comment: Before running to vbs file, we need kept our webpage in opened and after we need to double click on the vbs file , it's need to continue automation on already opened webpage.

Comment: Because of this, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239470, you have to let the vbscript open Internet Explorer for you, or it won't be possible to send commands to the page. Try it just to see if works.